# Is there a way to make NetBeans ensure a newline at the end of a file?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I couldn't find this option in the settings, nor could I find a plugin solving this problem. I googled a lot. Maybe I missed something. Does anyone know how to do it?

If it matters, I'm using NetBeans 7.1 Beta.

Comment: I've switched to [IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) a long time ago and now I'm finally enjoying my IDE. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my own research and lack of any solutions from others, I come to the conclusion that this is impossible.

Comment: this may just be the worst answer out there :)

Comment: Trying to find out the same thing... Is this something that could be done with a plugin or anything similar?  Kinda of a PITA to have to remember to put the line on there each time...

Comment: There is a plugin called "EOF Line Feed" which does just that, and can be installed simply through Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins. (http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56323/eof-line-feed)

Answer (score 3):

I found this plugin for Netbeans 8: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56323/eof-line-feed

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to edit your file template to include the newline.

Comment: What if I accidentally deleted a line after I created a file from a template? And do I have to change templates for every file type?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294451/how-the-change-the-line-ending-used-in-netbeans

Comment: My question is about EOF — not EOL.

Answer (score 0):

For current versions of NetBeans there is the "No Newline Resolver" plugin that can be installed through the plugin manager or downloaded here:

https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=33

https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-nonewline-resolver

Configuration can be found at: Options > Miscellaneous > No Newline Resolver